# Does jQuery retrieve all assets when getting a page via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I retrieve a page with jQuery's ajax function, but only extract out a portion of the returned content and insert that portion into the DOM (similar in theory to "pjax", but not using that library), does jQuery attempt to load any related assets (JS, CSS, images) that are linked to from portions of the retrieved page that were *not* inserted into the DOM?

What I'm trying to verify here is that I'm not being ridiculously inefficient with this method of loading page content (that is, by just retrieving an entire page and "slicing out" the portion of the content I need, as opposed to rendering a partial on the server or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ajax response` doesn't come with all attached document.
At the time when you attach `image,css and js` to `dom element`, Browser creates a `GET request` to your `specified path` to fetch the document.
Write down a simple AJAX code and then check `Net tab in firebug` or `Network tab in chrome`, you will get complete idea of `client server communication`. These tools are really awesome while working with `AJAX`.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because the browser dev tools were not showing me *any* assets loaded after the initial page load (that is, I wasn't seeing the images etc. loaded at the time they were inserted into the DOM). Perhaps that was a bug in an old version or something, or something specific to the site I was building at the time.

Comment: Install firebug its simply great. And ya, This eagerness makes good developers !! Keep it up

Answer (score 1):

No, jQuery doesn't automatically load images or CSS from an ajax response. It treats a HTML response as plain text. When you slice the HTML for what you need, jQuery is still parsing the whole document so it would be better to have the server side output only the portion you need.

Alternatively you could return the portion you need as JSON and create the DOM elements on the client side.

Comment: Worth mentioning: The browser itself handles loading external files (images, css etc.) except if explicitly handled via JS/JQuery.